# CreateFile returns error INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (for COM port), and GetLastError returns "can't find file specified"

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I'm opening a port to communicate with a device and control the device, but the `CreateFile()` function returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

`GetLastError()` returns `2` which means it can't find the specified file.

My code is shown below:

```
wsprintf( szPort, "COM%d", nPort );
m_hIDComDev = CreateFile(szPort,
                         GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                         0, 
                         NULL, 
                         OPEN_EXISTING, 
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
                         NULL);
if (m_hIDComDev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD err=GetLastError();
}
```

Why does this problem occur?

Comment: @JesseGood, I have modified my question.

Comment: I suspect [HOWTO: Specify Serial Ports Larger than COM9](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831/en-us) this is the problem.

Comment: @JesseGood, thanks a lot! I find out that there is no COM2 port on my computer. So, what I can do now is to randomly change to a port that my computer has or I need to choose a specific one?

Comment: Well, wouldn't that depend on what you want to do? Open device manager to see a list of ports.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're not specifying the correct value for `lpFileName` for your serial port. You should be using this format:

```
"\\\\.\\COM%d"
```

Which will result in a string that looks like `\\.\COM1`, which is the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
char *szPort = _T("COM1"); // Change port number to your unused existing port
```

`_T` forces to keep szPort in ASCII.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the problem. The port string doesn't need to be in ASCII - _T forces the string to be in the current character width, which could be either char or wchar_t depending on compilation options, and I would expect CreateFile to compile as CreateFileA or CreateFileW to match.  The main purpose of _T is that it does the right thing to match the Win32 API calls.